# Проблема при скрапинге сайта

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь вытащить данные с сайта zakupki.mos.ru макросом Google таблиц, но выдает только начало кода страницы

```
function getPageContent(url) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("a1:b1");
  var cell = range.getCell(1,1);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://zakupki.mos.ru/#/offerauction/456060/view"); 
  var textResp  = response.getContentText();
  var start, end, name;
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    start = textResp.indexOf('Возможная ставка', end) + 17;
    start = textResp.indexOf('">', start) + 2;
    end = textResp.indexOf('</strong>', start);
    name = textResp.substring(start, end);

    cell.setValue(name);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно то что ты хочешь спарсить поддтягивается ajax'ом в формате json по этой ссылке https://zakupki.mos.ru/api/Cssp/OfferAuction/GetEntity?id=456060, меняй id и забирай нужные данные

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! А подскажите, как id подтягивать из ячейки, например, E1?

Comment: Примера под рукой нет, мануалы курить лень. Примерно так перебором   var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете этого сделать.

Это нормально, т.к. метод `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` возвращет ответ сервера, а не стостояние браузера после обработки этого ответа. В данном случае скрапинг не возможен.

Чтобы узнать, можно ли получить данные с сайта таким образом, можно установить расширение для браузера, которое отключает выполнение сценариев (например, [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje) для Chrome). То, что выведет браузер при включенном расширении, то же самое вернет и `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.